# How to import parent class from a separate .py file for building inherited class inside a driver script for Abaqus python (version 2.7.15)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, abaqus

I have the following file structure

```
src
|-main_file.py
|-utils
|    |-util_debug.py
|-classes
|    |-class_coupon_generic.py
|    |-class_coupon_fatigue_type_1.py
|    |-class_coupon_fatigue_type_2.py
```

The file `class_coupon_generic.py` contains a class named `coupon_generic` which will act as a parent class for different types of coupons in future development. The file `class_coupon_fatigue_type_1.py` contains a class named `coupon_fatigue_type_1` which is inherited from the parent class `coupon_generic`. I am keeping all the class files in the folder `classes`. Inside the `utils` folder, I have a driver script for debugging `util_debug.py`. I want to import the classes `coupon_generic` and `coupon_fatigue_type_1` (depending on which coupon I am working on) in this file to build the final coupon model.

How do I achieve that?

I tried to import the modules using `imp.load_source` and `importlib.import_module`; but I couldn't figure out a way to do that. I am getting some error like `name 'coupon_generic' is not defined`. If the class `coupon_generic` is defined inside the file `class_coupon_fatigue_type_1.py`, then the I can make the import work using `imp.load_source`, but that kind of defeats the whole purpose of having a parent class. In order to add any new method to the parent class later on, I have to go to separate scripts and modify them individually. What is the correct way of making such import work with classes having inheritance?

Also, I prefer a solution where I can make the import of `class_coupon_fatigue_type_1.py` from a string name because it will be varying for different coupon types and I can control that by just passing a string name of the file during debugging.

Comment: import ParentClass from parent_class.py doesn't work for you?

Comment: No. still getting the same error